# wysiwyg editor cannot make it work

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg

I try to install a  wysiwyg editor in my website. But I cannot make it.

Here is the  wysiwyg editor [enter](http://jhollingworth.github.io/bootstrap-wysihtml5/)

My code:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./assets/wysihtml5/src/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="./assets/wysihtml5/src/wysihtml5-0.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="./assets/wysihtml5/src/bootstrap-wysihtml5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./assets/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('.textarea').wysihtml5();
    </script>
```

And the text area:

```
<textarea id="textarea" required name="message" class="span8 border-radius-none" rows="8"></textarea>
```

I see the text area but without the buttons above it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to give the `textarea` a *class* of textarea (not id)

**or**

change your jQuery selector to

```
$('#textarea').wysihtml5();
```

Also, you may need to swap the order of your js files and put the jquery lib before your bootstrap-wysihtml5.js